# Python 2.5 String formatting problem!

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am trying to use the python 2.5 string formatting  however I have run into problem in the following example:

```
values = {
          'url': 'http://blabla.com',
          'link' : 'http://blabla.com',
          'username' : 'user',
          'spot'    : 0,
          'views'    : 10,
          'date'    : 3232312,
          'private' : 1, 

          }

query = """insert into hyves.Image (URL, StaticLink , HostUsername, SpotCount, ViewCount, UploadDate) values ('%(url)','%(link)','%(username)',%(spot),%(views),%(date), %(private) )""" % values

print query
```

It gives me the following error:ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 106.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: The [Sqlite3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) gives an example of how to do parameter substitution for SQL queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never use string formatting for composing sql queries like that! Use your database module to do the interpolation -- it will do it with correct escaping, so that this doesn't happen to you: http://xkcd.com/327/

In case you want to use that formatting for different things than sql, use `%(foo)s` (or `d`, or whatever format you need).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the dangers of formatting SQL queries like that

Comment: Well the reason I am doing this is that the SQL files are outputed to files and are going to be executed manually by me. So I don't care about sanitizing the input.

Comment: I think you should still care -- you are not going to validate it all by hand, and there always may be some stray `'` in the data.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the format characters, i.e.:

```
"INSERT INTO ... %(url)s, ..." % values
```

...if you want to format URL as a string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify [explicit conversion](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) flags:

```
query = """insert into hyves.Image (URL, StaticLink , HostUsername, SpotCount, ViewCount, UploadDate) values (%(url)s,%(link)s,%(username)s,%(spot)i,%(views)i,%(date)i, %(private)i )""" % values
```